# Configuring a RESTful VirtualHost on Apache 2.4 with PHP

Tags: php, apache, rest, http, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a RESTful API on a VirtualHost on my Apache 2.4 server (on Ubuntu).  I have a php file named `dbManager.php` which I am using a RewriteRule to look like an `api` directory. It's working great except for PUT and DELETE commands, which are returning 403 errors.  Here's a redacted version of my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerAdmin onigame@gmail.com
  ServerName servername.com
  ServerAlias *.servername.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /path/to/local/dir/

  <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    <Limit PUT DELETE>
      Require all granted
    </Limit>
  </Directory>

  # RESTful services provided for the fake "api" directory
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /dbManager.php/$1 [L]

  ServerSignature On

  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</VirtualHost>
```

Well, the PUT and DELETE still aren't working and returning 403.  I'm also worried that I don't really want to allow PUT and DELETE everywhere on the directory, but only through the dummy `api` directory.  What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve my question, but I don't really understand *why* it works:

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerAdmin onigame@gmail.com
  ServerName servername.com
  ServerAlias *.servername.com

  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /path/to/local/dir/

  <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  <Directory /path/to/local/dir/>
    Require all granted
    Satisfy All
  </Directory>

  # RESTful services provided for the fake "api" directory
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ /dbManager.php/$1 [L]

  ServerSignature On

  AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</VirtualHost>
```

Best I can figure out, getting a 403 means that it's access being blocked, and not the type of HTTP request (which would result in a 405, not a 403).  And the access problem is on the local directory, so it needs a special section for it.  But I really don't understand why the two lines I put there make things work.  The `Require` directive, that sort of makes sense.  But the `Satisfy` directive, from what I can tell from the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#satisfy), should default to `All`.

And yet when I remove either line, it doesn't work.